# Using the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and let $p$ be a prime that divides the order of $G$. Use the **Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups** to show that $G$ contains an element of order $p$.

The Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups states that a finite abelian group $G$ is the direct summation of cyclic groups, each one of them are of prime power order.

For this problem, if $p$ divides $G$, then $G$ must have an order of $np^k$, where $n$ and $k$ are  positive integers. So applying the fundamental theorem, I get the direct sum
$$C_n \oplus C_{p^k}$$
with elementary divisors of $n$ and $p$, and with an invariant factor of $np$ (so the direct sum is isomorphic to the group $C_{np}$. Seeing that there is $C_p$ from the direct sum above, does this suffice to show that $G$ contains an element of order $p$ (or a subgroup of order $p$ that is generated by the element)?

Comment: What if the order of $G$ is $np^k$?

Comment: So that means we could have direct sums $C_n \oplus C_{p} \oplus C_{p}$, and $C_n \oplus C_{p} \oplus C_{p} \oplus C_{p}$, and all the way up to $C_n \oplus C_{p} \oplus C_{p} \oplus \cdots \oplus C_{p}$ ($k$ terms of $C_{p}$)?

Comment: Not necessarily. $C_p \oplus C_p \not\simeq C_{p^2}$ as the latter has elements of order $p^2$ while the former does not.

Comment: So the only direct sum that I find (that is isomorphic to $G=C_{np^k}$) is $C_n \oplus C_{p^k}$.

Comment: So you have your group of prime power order. Can you show it has to have an element of order $p$?

Comment: That is not true though. Think about $(\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/ 4 \mathbb{Z}$ one has an element of order 4, one does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If $g \in G$ has order $p^n$, then $g^{p^{n-1}}$ has order $p$.

Comment: Because $p^k = p^{k-1} p$, so that's why we use the new element $g^{p^{k-1}}$, right?

Comment: yep! That is correct

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer, but I can't fit this properly in the comment section.

At this point, I have a group of prime power order, in particular $C_n \oplus C_{p^k}$. My textbook (Hungerford, 2nd edition) is suggesting as a hint to use Theorem 7.8, which says

> Let $G$ be an additive group and let $a \in G$.
>
> - If $a$ has infinite order, then the elements $a^k$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, are all distinct.
> - If $a^i = a^j$ with $i \not= j$, then $a$ has finite order.
> - If $a$ has finite order $n$, then 
>     $$a^k=e \text{ if and only if } n \mid k$$
>     and $$a^i = a^j \text{ if and only if } i \equiv j \text{ (mod $n$)}$$
> - If $a$ has order $n$ and $n = td$ with $d > 0$, then $a^t$ has order $d$.

...in order to find an element of order $p$. The fourth bullet helps finish the job.